# Scala @elidable causes compiler to crash

Tags: scala

I have a debugger trait in my code, which is marked with @elidable, e.g.:

```
@elidable(FINE) trait MyDebugger {
...
}
```

and one of my classes extends MyDebugger, to use some of the methods provided by that trait. However when I set the -Xelide-below to a value higher than FINE (which I believe is 500?), the compiler crashes.

So I'm obviously missing something, but what? Maybe I'm not understanding what the compiler does when my code tries to reference code that's been elided out?

When I set '-Xelide-below 600' for example, I get the following.

```
Error:scalac: Error: Illegal tree in gen: null
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: Illegal tree in gen: null
    at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting$class.abort(Reporting.scala:59)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.icode.GenICode$ICodePhase.gen(GenICode.scala:151)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.icode.GenICode$ICodePhase.gen(GenICode.scala:71)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.icode.GenICode$ICodePhase.gen(GenICode.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.icode.GenICode$ICodePhase.gen(GenICode.scala:67)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.icode.GenICode$ICodePhase.apply(GenICode.scala:63)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$applyPhase$1.apply$mcV$sp(Global.scala:441)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.withCurrentUnit(Global.scala:432)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:441)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:399)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:399)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:399)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.icode.GenICode$ICodePhase.run(GenICode.scala:55)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1500)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1487)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1482)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1580)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:126)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:102)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:29)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

(edit: Scala 2.11.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that it crashes, but the usage is to apply the annotation to methods.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/#scala.annotation.elidable

When eliding, it replaces method bodies with a default value and also effectively inlines the value.

That's not meaningful for arbitrary symbols.

Edit: fix under https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10068

Comment: Thanks. Then the compiler should raise an error even if the elide-below is set to a value that causes the code not to be elided out. Futhermore, why not allow it for traits, and simply infer that if the trait is marked as elidable, everything in the trait is elidable.

Comment: I agree with your points. If it were a macro, the annotation could add itself to eligible members.

Comment: Since I just fixed my code to work around this, might as well throw in another issue: I had some code like logger.debug(myElidedMethod()),  myElidedMethod() was returning a string, and when I elided out the method, it compiled okay, but I had a runtime error since logger.debug() freaked out. That should also be a compile-time check, it's too dangerous for this to not be caught until runtime.

Comment: I'd expect a string-valued method to elide to null, not an empty string. With a custom macro for your method, of course, you could check the elide level and emit an empty string as required.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but if the method was Elided to null and the method expected a string, the compiler should have caught it. That is what I was hoping at least.

Comment: That's an idea, eliding to empty string. Go's default value for string is empty, not null.